# Why is Ansible ignoring delegate_to parameter?

Tags: ansible

I have a very simple playbook:

```
- hosts: test
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug: msg="{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      run_once: yes
      delegate_to: "host2"
```

and inventory file:

```
host1 ansible_ssh_host="1.2.3.4"
host2 ansible_ssh_host="1.2.3.5"

[test]
host1
host2
```

And the result of play:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1 -> host2] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "host1"
}
```

To be complete, whatever I add to `delegate_to`, even some random strings, the result is always `"msg": "host1"`.

How can I correctly delegate this task to groups.test.1 or any other host?

EDIT:

```
- hosts: test
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: 1
      shell: "hostname -f"
      run_once: yes
      delegate_to: "host2"
      register: result

    - name: debug
      debug: msg="{{ ansible_host }} {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ result.stdout }}"
      run_once: yes
```

play output:

```
TASK [command] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1 -> None]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "1.2.3.4 host1 host2"
}
```

Ansible 2.3.x

Ansible 2.4.0

Answer (score 6):

`inventory_hostname` doesn't change when you use `delegate_to` to allow you to "keep track" of context you are in, but other variables do change.

You can test with:

```
- name: debug
  debug: msg="{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ ansible_host }}"
  run_once: yes
  delegate_to: "host2"
```

You should get: `host1 1.2.3.5`

Comment: No, does not work at all. Still returns `host1 1.2.3.4`

Comment: Even running shell: "hostname -f" with delegate_to proves that the command is ran against host1.

Comment: Please add example of `hostname -f` with `-vvv` verbosity to your original post.

Comment: Now I'm confused, because I'm seeing semi-correct output; hostname output is from host2, but ansible_host and inventory_hostname from host1. Finally I managed to run my tasks with `when: inventory_hostname == 'host2'` that works for me but I'm not happy about this.

Comment: Your first task is delegated to host2, so you get `host2` from `result.stdout`; But your second task is not delegated and executed on host1, so you get `1.2.3.4` from `ansible_host`. Everything works as expected.